# haskell hang up (randomR,unsafePerformIO)

Tags: haskell

**I write genetic algorithm on haskell GHCI**

When I imput `children ["+ 1 2","* 3 4"]` GHCI writes `"` and hang up :( 
All functions work separately, the mistake arises only when using functions together(crossover, rnd3,gNt work norm separately) and with random numbers.

code:

-----Random IO Int-----------------------------------

```
rnd3 :: Int->IO Int
rnd3 x= do 
  oldState <- getStdGen
  let (result,newState) = randomR (1,x) oldState
  setStdGen newState
  return (result)
```

----------------getNtexp----------------------------------------

```
gNt :: String->Int->String
gNt l n = unwords ( gNtWords n (words l) )


opX :: [String] -> [String]
opX (fst:x) = helper 1 x []
     where
    helper 0 l ans = reverse ans
    helper n (fst:x) ans = if ( fst == "+" || fst == "-" || fst == "*" || fst == "/" ) then helper (n+1) x (fst:ans)
                        else helper (n-1) x (fst:ans)

opY :: [String] -> [String]
opY (fst:x) = helper 1 x []
     where
    helper 0 l ans = l
    helper n (fst:x) ans = if ( fst == "+" || fst == "-" || fst == "*" || fst == "/" ) then helper (n+1) x (fst:ans)
                        else helper (n-1) x (fst:ans)


gNtWords:: Int -> [String] -> [String]

gNtWords n [] = []
gNtWords 0  l = l
gNtWords 1 l = (opX l)
gNtWords 2 l = (opY l)
gNtWords n l = if( n < (length (opX l) + 2 ) ) then  gNtWords (n - 2 )  (opX l) 
            else  gNtWords (n - (length (opX l)) - 1 ) (opY l)
-- ( gNtWords (n + nodeCount (opX l) ) (opY l) ) )
```

----------------------Replace NtSubExp----------------------------------

```
rNt :: String->String->Int->String
rNt expTree newExp n = unwords (rNtWord n (words expTree) (words newExp) )

rNtWord:: Int -> [String] -> [String] -> [String]

rNtWord n l newExp = replacer n l newExp 
                            where 
replacer 0 l newExp  = newExp       
replacer 1 (l) newExp  = (   (++) [head l]  (  (++) newExp (opY l)  )   )
replacer 2 (l) newExp = (  (++) [head l] ( (++) (opX l) newExp )  )
replacer n l newExp = if( n < (length (opX l) + 2 ) ) then (++) [head l]  ((++) (replacer (n - 2)(opX l) newExp ) (opY l))
                            else (++) [head l] (  (++) (opX l) (replacer(n-(length(opX l))-1)(opY l) newExp ))
```

---------------------Crossover------------------------------------------

```
crossover :: String->String->String

crossover exp1 exp2 = let rnd1 = ( unsafePerformIO (rnd3 (nCount exp1) ) ) -1
                        ;rnd2 = (unsafePerformIO (rnd3 (nCount exp2) )) - 1
                        in  rNt exp1 (gNt exp2 rnd2) rnd1
```

----------NormalDistribution---------------------------------------

```
norm :: Int -> Float

norm size =  let sizeF = fromIntegral (size) 
                ;rnd1 = ( fromIntegral ( unsafePerformIO (rnd3 2000 ) ) )/1000 - 1
                ;rnd2 = ( fromIntegral ( unsafePerformIO (rnd3 2000 ) ) )/1000 - 1
                ;s = rnd1*rnd1 +rnd2*rnd2
                in  ( cos (2.0 * 3.14 * rnd1 ) * sqrt( -2.0*log(rnd2) ))
```

------------------------makeChildren--------------

```
parent:: [String] -> String

parent pop = let rnd =  ( unsafePerformIO (rnd3 (length pop) ) ) - 1   
            in (!!) pop rnd
```

**if rnd in parent not random number (for example rnd=1 or rnd=2), all works**

```
children:: [String] -> String
children pop = crossover (parent pop) (parent pop)
```

**or if here `(parent pop)`  or `(++) (parent pop) (parent pop)`all works**

In what mistake? It seems to me, or I somehow not so take random numbers (in other functions they works normally) Sorry for my English (and haskell))

Comment: That is not a legitimate use of `unsafePerformIO`.  If your next question is "what is an acceptable use" then the answer is simple: don't use `unsafePerformIO`.

Comment: How it is possible to receive the casual differently? I very long suffered to receive a random number, I don't know how it can be done without transformation use, differently I wouldn't use it. It is my first program in haskell, be indulgent. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Some alternative methods: You could use `MonadRandom`, you could create an infinite list of randoms and consume values from that list, you could run everything in the IO monad, or you could pass around the StdGen instead of using a global (mutable) StdGen.

Comment: @haskellLover You can write you code in the IO monad, you don't have to exit IO to do computations.  The point of the IO monad in Haskell is to force you to separate your pure and impure code.  Write what functions you can purely, and whenever you need to generate a random number make that function perform the IO, and leave it in the type signature.  Using do notation will help make this easy and elegant.  If you want an easier way to generate random numbers, look at the MonadRandom package.

Comment: @bheklilr Thanks, I tru

    `index:: [String] -> IO Int -> String  -----
            index (x:xs) 1 = x   ------

             index (x:xs) n = index xs (n-1)`

You can show on this simple example how to return the n'th element of the list

Comment: You can't pattern match on `IO` types, and `1` has type `Int`, not `IO Int`.  These are very different types in Haskell.  I would write that function the same way, but with `index :: [a] -> Int -> a`, then if I could use it as `someAction :: [String] -> IO String; someAction strings = do { i <- someFuncToGetIndex; return $ index strings i }`.  I would also recommend just using the `!!` indexing function, no need to write your own.

Comment: @bheklilr Yes, it's good, but someFuncToGetIndex must return Int (not IO) and problem with random inbex remains.You using MonadRandom and "<-" is unpack ??  You wrote, what I can do everything in IO monad,but how to take an element in the list with IO Int index?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27041993 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to use `unsafePerformIO` here, or pretty much ever. Just pretend it doesn't exist. It won't make your code better, easier to read or write, and often will have the side effect of your code not working. There are [many good tutorials](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tutorials) on the basics - specifically, monads. I highly suggest you pick one and go through the entire thing (the first one is good).

As a side note, your definition of `rnd3` is exactly equivalent to `rnd3 x = randomRIO (1,x)`

```
crossover exp1 exp2 = do
  rnd1 <- rnd3 (nCount exp1) 
  rnd2 <- rnd3 (nCount exp2)
  return $ rNt exp1 (gNt exp2 (rnd2 - 1)) (rnd1 - 1)
```

Wherever you had `let x = ... unsafePerformIO ..`, just remove that and replace it with `x <- ...`. Note that you can't write `rnd1 <- rnd3 (nCount exp1) - 1` but you can write `rnd1 <- fmap (subtract 1) $ rnd3 (nCount exp1)`.

You can have `let` in a `do` block. The syntax is slightly different; you don't need to write `in` (or rather, everything following `let` is implicitly the `in`.)

```
norm sizeF = do
  let sizeF = fromIntegral size -- this is unused?
  rnd1' <- rnd3 2000  
  rnd2' <- rnd3 2000 

  let
    rnd1 = rnd1' / 1000 - 1
    rnd2 = rnd2' / 1000 - 1
    s = rnd1*rnd1 +rnd2*rnd2
  return $ cos (2.0 * 3.14 * rnd1) * sqrt(-2.0*log rnd2)
```

One key thing to remember is you can't escape from `IO`. The last statement in a `do` block must have the type `IO a`.

Answer (score -1):

**My decision:** at first I wrote the generator of prime numbers on the basis of moving Int

```
myRandom :: Int -> Int -> Int

myRandom gen range= let a = 6364136223846793005
                    ;c = 1442695040888963407
                    ;m = 2^32--2^64
                in   mod(mod (a*gen + c) (2^16)) range
```

With the two in 32\64 degrees division into zero turns out?

Received casual Int is the following entrance value of the generator. Then I understood that with we conceal success StdGen can store, instead of Int in a defiant function

```
rand :: StdGen->Int->(Int,StdGen)
rand gen range= randomR (0,range-1)  gen
```

First gen get with mkStdGen (numb from my rnd3 with unsafePerformIO ..sorry )